# Moving PictureBox using Timer

Tags: vb.net, winforms, timer, picturebox

Basically what I'm trying to do is to make a picture box go up, then left, then down, then right, all based on timer ticks. I'm fairly new so I don't really know what's wrong. If you guys could give a simple answer or a better approach, that'd be great.

```
Dim slides As Integer

slides += 10
If slides < 20 Then
  PictureBox1.Left += 10
ElseIf slides > 20 AndAlso slides < 40 Then
  PictureBox1.Top += 10
ElseIf slides > 40 AndAlso < 60 Then
  PictureBox1.Left -= 10
ElseIf slides > 60 AndAlso < 80 Then
  PictureBox1.Top -= 10
Else
  slides = 0
End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things.  Make sure your `slides` integer is outside the Tick event.  Also, make sure to cover the condition of "equals", which your code doesn't check for, so `slides` is constantly falling into the "else" category and setting back to zero.  That is, when `slides` equals 20, you don't have a condition that satisfies it, so it resets to zero.

```
Private slides As Integer

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
  slides += 10
  If slides <= 20 Then
    PictureBox1.Left += 10
  ElseIf slides > 20 AndAlso slides <= 40 Then
    PictureBox1.Top += 10
  ElseIf slides > 40 AndAlso slides <= 60 Then
    PictureBox1.Left -= 10
  ElseIf slides > 60 AndAlso slides <= 80 Then
    PictureBox1.Top -= 10
  Else
    slides = 0
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is why I love this site. Thanks so much!